# dynamic style-sheet adding in web component

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a simple web component.

```
const template = document.createElement('template');
template.innerHTML = `
    <style>
        h3 {
            color: coral;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img class="card-img-top" />
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
    </div>
`;

addStyle(`https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css`);

class UserCard extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
        this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
        this.shadowRoot.querySelector('h5').innerText = this.getAttribute('name');
        this.shadowRoot.querySelector('img').src = this.getAttribute('avatar');

    }
}

window.customElements.define('user-card', UserCard);

function addStyle(href) {              
    var link = document.createElement('link');
    link.id = 'id2';
    link.rel = 'stylesheet';
    link.href = href;
    document.head.appendChild(link); 
}
```

I can see the stylesheet added in `head` but the bootstrap card css is not working.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM) blocks the document level CSS from being applied to the shadow root - this is the whole concept of web components: they allow you to deploy a containerized component that is protected from style and layout changes that are applied in the document. This is a feature, not a bug.

To apply style to the web component, you need to have the style appended to the shadow root itself. See the attached reference above for full details, but generally I would have implemented your code like this:

```js
class UserCard extends HTMLElement {
    styleURL = 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css';
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
        this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
        this.shadowRoot.querySelector('h5').innerText = this.getAttribute('name');
        this.shadowRoot.querySelector('img').src = this.getAttribute('avatar');

        let style = document.createElement('style');
        style.textContent = `@import url("${this.styleURL}");`
        this.shadowRoot.appendChild(style);
    }
}
```